# Aligning NSTextField and an Image

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield, nstextfieldcell, nstablecellview

I am trying to align an NSTextField and an NSImageView.. My current code is below. I have tried a bunch of different approaches including subclassing NSTextFieldCell (found here on SO), messing around with the frame of the text field, and tweaking constraints, but I just can't get it.. No matter what I do, it looks like the screenshot below..

I also have discovered that when I don't apply a font to the label, alignment works as I would expect -- it is vertically aligned with the image.

So the question is, a) why in the world does applying a font screw up the alignment, and b) how do I get around this, ideally in a dynamic way that will adapt if i change the font at runtime..

[image]

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self) {
        NSView *spacer1 = [[NSView alloc] init];
        [spacer1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [self addSubview:spacer1];

        NSView *spacer2 = [[NSView alloc] init];
        [spacer2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [self addSubview:spacer2];

        NSImage *icon = [NSImage imageNamed:@"05-arrow-west"];
        NSImageView *iconView = [[NSImageView alloc] init];
        [iconView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [iconView setImage:icon];

        [self addSubview:iconView];

        NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14];
        NSTextField *label = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
        [label setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [label setEditable:NO];
        [label setSelectable:NO];
        [label setBezeled:NO];
        [label setDrawsBackground:NO];

        [label setFont:font];
        [label setTextColor:[NSColor lightGrayColor]];
        [label setStringValue:@"Test String"];


        [self addSubview:label];

        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(iconView, label, spacer1, spacer2);

        [self addConstraints:
                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[spacer1(>=0)][iconView]-5-[label][spacer2(==spacer1)]|"
                                                        options: 0
                                                        metrics:nil
                                                          views:views]];

        [self addConstraints:
                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[iconView]|"
                                                        options: 0
                                                        metrics:nil
                                                          views:views]];

        [self addConstraints:
                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[label]|"
                                                        options: 0
                                                        metrics:nil
                                                          views:views]];

        [self setContentHuggingPriority:200 forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical];
        [iconView setContentHuggingPriority:200 forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical];
        [label setContentHuggingPriority:200 forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Oh, that's pretty simple.. Why in the world aren't they lined up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this did it:

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBaseline
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:iconView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:0]];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem related to AppKit calculating incorrect metrics for certain fonts. *Helvetica Neue* and its variants are susceptible to this problem. Autolayout depends on the `intrinsicContentSize` of the `NSTextField`, which uses broken metrics to calculate the appropriate size to display the text. The only way I know of to work around this problem is to use magic offsets in your layout constraints to manually align the text.

Comment: Well that.. sucks... Can you point me at a sample of how to do magic offsets in a dynamic way? I can get it to align using |-5-[label(==26)]-5-| but it's basically breaking auto layout -- if i change any other constraints, i have to go mess with these values..

Comment: I don't have significant experience with Autolayout, but I believe the `constant` parameter of `NSLayoutConstraint -constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:` may be helpful to you. Essentially you just want to offset the Y origin of the text field by a fixed number.